# MAC address spoofing in Windows 7 - 00 as first two digits?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mac-address

I've followed [this guide on MAC address spoofing](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-change-or-spoof-mac-address-in-windows-xp-vista-server-20032008-mac-os-x-unix-and-linux/).

I'm trying to change the MAC address for my wireless adapter. I seem to be able to change it when doing the registry edit, but only if the second digit is something other than 0 (I think it has to be 2). I've tried in the device manager, from SMAC, and from the registry, and I can't seem to set the first two digits to 00 (it just reverts to the initial MAC address).

Is there any way around this, or am I out of luck? Is this a Windows  7 restriction, or is it the firmware on the wireless adapter that doesn't seem to work? I've also followed the instructions on that page to try and change it in Ubuntu as well, but didn't seem to have any luck there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My wireless card doesn't have that option. I followed the instructions at the link I specified, which led me to edit it directly in the registry. Doing so does not work if you set the first two digits to 00.

Comment: @Nate: Those might be reserved, why do you need them to explicitly be 00?

Comment: The cheap student housing I'm in restricts access to their wifi network by MAC address. I've got my main computer and a server running Ubuntu, and they haven't been able to give me another access code. I was going to try and see if there was any way for me to clone the MAC address from my original adapter. Don't think it's going to work, though. I'll talk to them again to see if I can get another access code. Or I might look into internet connection sharing between the two, but not sure if I'll get it to work with Ubuntu and Windows 7. Might just need to get a router.

Comment: Also, after doing a bit of research, cloning the MAC address on the same network sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Cloning the MAC address sure will end up giving you problems if you want to run both simultaneously. Also, LAN MAC addresses don't guarantee you with WiFi access. Best to either talk to the owner or get yourself a router. Good luck getting your laptop connected...

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the best course of action. They don't seem to keen on giving out extra codes, so I'll probably go with a router. Now to figure out if Ubuntu and Windows 7 will get along, with WiFi Connection -> Windows 7 -> Router -> Ubuntu.

Comment: Cloning MAC is not so bad idea! I used it once. Usually that networks are not so well-secured. And if a "working" user disconnects from that WiFi, he usually stays "logged on" within some minutes (usually/most frequently). And when you go then with his MAC, it thinks that you've returned and gets you access to internet...

Answer (score 3):

Just install "CommView for WiFi" as demo software, and replace your card wifi driver with modded CommView driver, that don't have mac restriction (ProgramFiles(X86)\CommViewWiFi\Driver). Then you can uninstall the demo.

Comment: Heh get +1. I wanted to answer this way too =)