# Windows 8 Force MAC Address Spoof

Tags: windows-8, mac-address, spoofing

Just to make this short, I've tried almost everything I found on Google to spoof my MAC addres (Registry, SMAC, NetworkAdress in Adapter Settings, etc.) and none worked. This is because of something I just discovered a while ago where Spoofing with Windows Vista and beyond had restrictions with the 2nd digit of the MAC Address (2, 6, A, E).

The title says it all. How can I force unsupported MAC addresses? If you think it is impossible, kindly state why and why Windows made this restriction. Thanks!

Comment: **I would considering not asking us to speculate the reason Windows has the restriction.**

Comment: I think this should do it: [superuser.com/questions/376212](http://superuser.com/questions/376212/mac-address-spoofing-in-windows-7-00-as-first-two-digits?rq=1)

Comment: If you remove the "why does Windows have this restriction" I will remove my downvote and retract my vote to close.  Of course it does indeed look like its a duplicate question though so it might not matter.